# How to pass our own runner instead of BlockJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: junit4

Actually i wanted to override the runChild() method of BlockJUnit4ClassRunner hence I created a class (MyRunner.java) and exetended BlockJUnit4ClassRunner and overridden the runChild() method.

```
public class MyRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner
{

@Override
public void runChild(final FrameworkMethod method, RunNotifier notifier) {
    System.out.println("<--------- Inside MyRunner.runChild() -------->");
    // my code goes here
}

}
```

But the call doesn't go to my overridden method (it doesn't even come to MyRunner.java) and calls BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild() method only.
I debugged and found that this is because the runner passed to JunitCore.run(Runner runner) method is BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.
I'm not sure on this but I think this might be coming from JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass() method .

```
// This is JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass(Class<?>) method
public Runner runnerForClass(Class<?> testClass) throws Throwable 
{
    return new BlockJUnit4ClassRunner(testClass);
}
```

I tried to override the JUnit4Builder.runnerForClass() also but that also did not helped. 
Can anyone let me know  if there's any way to pass the MyRunner or any means to override the BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably not using the [@RunWith](http://api.dpml.net/junit/4.2/org/junit/runner/RunWith.html) annotation. In order to use your own Runner you need to annotate every TestClass with the @RunWith annotation. This will make sure, that your Test is executed with that runner.

Example:

```
@RunWith(MyRunner .class)
public class MyTest
{ 
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that indeed worked. Was away for few days hence could not test but verified today and it worked as expected.